# Could not convert or access JSON object from PHP json_encode

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, json

Could not convert or access JSON object from PHP json_encode

```
<?php
$f_array = array();   // ---- Custom Line 1
for ($i=0; $i < $interval; ++$i) 
{
    $t_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($k_date1 . "+ $i day"));    

    $f_array = array();
    $f_query = mysql_query("select COUNT(j.job_id) as `job_count`
                            from jobs j
                            where j.job_posted_date 
                            LIKE '%$t_date%' and j.job_status = 3");

    if (mysql_num_rows($f_query) > 0) 
    {
        $f_query_data = mysql_fetch_array($f_query);
        $f_count = $f_query_data['job_count'];

        $f_array = array_push($f_array, $f_count);   // ---- Custom Line 2
        // $f_array[] = $f_count;   // ---- Custom Line 3
    }
}

$j_array = json_encode($f_array);
?>
```

I get only one value ie `1` in Javascript, with `enabling` `Custom Line 1` & `Custom Line 2`.

And when i `enabled` `Custom Line 3` and disable `Custom Line 1` & `Custom Line 2`. then i get output good as in from database

```
<script>
var j_array = "<?php echo $j_array; ?>";
</script>
```

### Result 1

```
<script>
var j_array = "1";
</script>
```

### Result 2

```
<script>
var j_array = "["0","0","0","2","0","0","0","0","1","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","2","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","25","0","0","0","0","0","7","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","1","0","0","1","1","47","0","1","1","0","0","0","0","0","0","3","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"]";
</script>
```

And i have attached an image below..

[image]

Now how can i access the `Result 2` in an order of an `Array` or any other method.

And i tried using below

```
<script>
    alert(j_array);
</script>

<script>
    alert(j_array.0); // as an Object mightbe .. or I dont have any idea on it, so experimenting ..
</script>
```

**What i need or Need Help**

Its not giving any result as `0` is a `integer` not `string`.. And if its an `Array` then its also tricky.. there are `n` number of `String 0`.. so how can i call one by one. or To convert into Javascript array.

***Note: `Result 2` is desired output, but its not in `Array`***

Comment: do you work in clean PHP code or are you using framework or some template engine as smarty ?

Comment: Just remove the "" at var j_array = "<?php echo $j_array; ?>";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var j_array = <?php echo $j_array; ?>;
```

Without " "

When you put the brackets you escape the json_encoded array at your javascript..

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but true nonetheless!

Comment: where is that $interval comming from at your loop ?

Comment: `$interval` is defined. and its working.. good..

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at php manual for [`array_push()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php).

> Returns the new number of elements in the array.

So the correct syntax is:

```
array_push($f_array, $f_count);   // without `$f_array = ` at the beginning
```

Answer (score 2):

Either:

```
array_push($f_array, $f_count);
```

or

```
$f_array[] = $f_count;
```

Definitely *not* `$f_array = array_push($f_array, $f_count)`.

Next, no quotes around the JSON array, since that becomes a Javascript string:

```
var j_array = <?php echo $j_array; ?>;
```

Next, Javascript array elements are accessed as such:

```
j_array[0]
```

*Not* `j_array.0`.

Comment: Why i cant use `array_push`, if used it return only one single value.. 

And Good explaination.

Comment: Please RTFM entry for [`array_push`](http://php.net/array_push). It returns the new number of elements in the array (i.e. a number), not the new array. The array is modified in-place via references, you do not need the return value. You're just overwriting your just-pushed-into array with a number.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the function signature of [`array_push()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php).

It does not return the extended array, but rather uses the first argument as a variable reference and returns an integer. On *Custom Line 2*, you are assigning the return value of `array_push()` to you array, this is why you're always getting `1` as a result.

Remove the assignation on Custom Line 2, like shown below, and you'll get what you expect:

```
array_push($f_array, $f_count);
```